# using TMultipartContentParser to uplaod files

Tags: delphi, delphi-xe5, isapi

after Delphi Xe5 update 2, the ReqMulti.pas has been removed from the product. what is a replacement? Previously I was using TMultipartContentParser from reqMulti unit to upload files. what should I use to upload files since TMultipartContentParser is gone? TWebRequest.Files is not working: file count is always 0

thank you

Comment: Possible duplicate or at least related to:
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15385808/delphi-xe-isapi-webbroker-file-upload?rq=1

Comment: Weird, according to [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21942850/using-tmultipartcontentparser-to-uplaod-files) and [this](http://edn.embarcadero.com/article/43522), removal should have been *fixed* in update 2.