# Delphi 7 ISAPI WebBroker file upload

Tags: delphi, delphi-7, webbroker

I am trying to accept file uploads in a Delphi 7 Webbroker CGI.

I'm using Shiv Kumar's TMsMultipartParser, but I have a problem with Chrome. I can't access the parsed data (surprisingly, Explorer works fine).

This is my code:

```
with TMsMultipartFormParser.Create do
begin
    Parse(Request);

    lsExternalID:=ContentFields.Values['external_id'];

    if (lsExternalID='') then
        raise Exception.Create('No external ID');

    for i := 0 to Files.Count -1 do
    begin
        lsFileName:=files[i].FileName;
        //Rename file using external ID (not included for simplicity)
        Files[i].SaveToFile(lsFilename);
    end;
    Response.Content := 'OK';
    free;
end;
```

As suggested [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/15386511), I tried to use http://www.mrsoft.org/Delphi/MultipartParser.pas but I can't compile it. It uses a unit called UniversalUtils that I can't find anywhere.

I know this is a very obsolete technology. Almost all references to it have already disappeared from the web (believe me, I have searched). Buy any help would be deeply appreciated.

Thanks.

Comment: What does "can't access the parsed data" mean exactly? Do you get an error? The data isn't there as it should be? Is the exception being raised? You haven't specified a problem.

Comment: just remove UniversalUtils from the uses.

Comment: Yes remove this unit - I accidentally moved some functions from there into this unit (which we use in our company)... I uploaded a new version of that file to my site which includes the missing functions.

Comment: Thank you guys. @bummi, I got compiler error when I removed it.

Comment: Thanks @mrabat, you're very kind. I tried it, but I still got an error with a call to "UTF8ToString". I then realized that I'm using a unit that is meant to adapt Shiv's multiparser to Unicode. I am using Delphi 7 with ANSI strings (no unicode support), therefore I don't really need it. Then I saw that I could use Delphi 7's TMultipartContentParser in ReqMulti.pas. I didn't find any example, but it wasn't hard to figure out. I had been using Shiv's Multiparser because the project had been started on Delphi 5, and there was no parser included. Thanks for your help!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I finally solved my problem, thanks to @mrabat.
This project started in Delphi 5. It was later upgraded to Delphi 7 (it can't be upgraded further, because many parts can't support Unicode strings, we use ANSI).
We were using Shiv's TMsMultipartParser because Delphi 5 didn't have any parser included. 
Delphi 7 has TMultipartContentParser in unit ReqMulti.pas, and it works perfectly.

For anyone that need an example, I'll post my working code:

```
with TMultipartContentParser.Create(Request) do
begin
    lsExternalID:=ContentFields.Values['external_id'];
    if (lsExternalID='') then
        raise Exception.Create('No external ID');

    for i := 0 to Request.Files.Count -1 do
    begin
        lsFileName:=Request.Files[i].FileName;
        //Rename file using external ID (not included for simplicity)
        TMemoryStream(Request.Files[i].Stream).SaveToFile(lsFilename);
    end;
    Response.Content := 'OK';
    Free;
end;
```

Answer (score 0):

I wrote something similar once here:
https://github.com/stijnsanders/xxm/blob/master/Delphi/common/xxmParams.pas#L159
but that may be tightly coupled with `SplitHeaderValue` that parses the header lines, and `TStreamNozzle` that throttles incoming data. (and `TXxmReqPar...` objects, and `IXxmContext`...)

(Of course you're warmly welcomed to accept file uploads with [xxm](http://xxm.sf.net/)...)

Comment: Thanks Stijn, but it turns out my problem was quite simple. I wasn't using the correct multipart parser.